# Why do arros of vectorfields grow in plots?

Tags: vector-fields

Let $v(x,y)=(x,y)$ be a vector field. Plottet, it looks like this:

[image]

So this is a very simple question: Why do the arrows get bigger in length the further away they are? It is clear to me, that if we take some random $v=(x_1,y_1)$ it's length describes how far it is away from the origin. Is that what the length of the arrows in the plot should indicate?

Comment: Most vector fields don't look like this.

Comment: Yes, in this case their length is equal to the distance from the origin. $|(x,y)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Does that mean, the length could also mean something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector field $V$ on $\mathbb R^2$ maps a point **p** to tangent vectors $V($**p**$)$. It's not necessary that this tangent vector has greater magnitude with **p** further from the origin. Let $V:(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)$ and you will have a constant vector field that gives you arrow of same magnitude everywhere and pointing in the same direction.

Comment: How would I have to rewrite my example, so I'd get arrows of the same length?

Comment: Make $V:(x,y)\rightarrow(u,v)$ such that $u^2+v^2=constant$ in Euclidean space.

Comment: thanks :) .....